# Convert Number to DayOfWeek List

Tags: windows, powershell, dayofweek

I've got an odd issue I'm running into and hoping someone here can help. I'm querying against a Scheduled Task on a Windows computer and getting the days when it is slated to execute. However, where I want to see something like "Sunday, Monday, Wednesday, Friday", I get "43".

```
$taskObject = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTestTask" -TaskPath "\Testing\" | Select-Object *
foreach ($trigger in $taskObject.Triggers) {
    write-host $trigger.DaysOfWeek
}
```

I poked at things a bit, but I'm coming up empty on how to easily convert "43" to the list of the selected days. Is there a function or something somewhere that I'm overlooking? How can I convert the listed number to `[DayOfWeek[]]$currentDays`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DaysOfTheWeek is a bitwise mask, with enumeration shown in it's document page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/weeklytrigger-daysofweek

Seeing that we can enumerate those in a hashtable, then use it to determine what days your task triggers on.

```
$DayofWeek=@{
    1='Sunday'
    2='Monday'
    4='Tuesday'
    8='Wednesday'
    16='Thursday'
    32='Friday'
    64='Saturday'
}
$DayofWeek.Keys | Where{$trigger.DaysOfTheWeek -band $_} | ForEach-Object {$Dayofweek[$_]}
```

With your example of 43 that would output Friday, Wednesday, Monday, and Sunday.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed. Just had to pipe it to 'Sort-Object' and I'm rolling forward.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to [@TheMadTechnician's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71592858/9164015):

```
[Flags()] enum DaysOfWeek {
    Sunday = 1
    Monday = 2
    Tuesday = 4
    Wednesday = 8
    Thursday = 16
    Friday = 32
    Saturday = 64
}

[DaysOfWeek]43

# Outputs:
# Sunday, Monday, Wednesday, Friday
```

[PowerShell Enum Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-7.2#flags-usage-example) - PowerShell 5.0 and above.